# Litespeed Enterprise not obeying .htaccess require rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, litespeed

I have the following folder structure

```
domain.com (/public_html/)
sub.domain.com (/public_html/sub/)
sub.domain.com/dir1/ (/public_html/sub/dir1/)
sub.domain.com/dir1/dir2/ (/public_html/sub/dir1/dir2/)
```

if I put the following in my .htaccess file at any of these directories

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

require valid-user
<RequireAny>
    Require ip x.x.x.x
</RequireAny>
```

It has no effect when loading any files in these directories.

Additionally if i want multiple require rules to have and/or then it gets a little more complicated for example

```
# Allowing Access via Password or one of the following IP Addresses

AuthName "Authorized Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswds/.htpasswd

<RequireAll>
require valid-user
<RequireAny>
    Require ip x.x.x.x
    Require ip y.y.y.y
</RequireAny>
</RequireAll>
```

Apache did follow these rules set, but switching to litespeed enterprise web server has meant that IP restrictions have been ignored

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? On LiteSpeed the modules execute in a different order, so you can find that mod_rewrite (for instance) ends up overriding mod_authz_core (and related auth mods) - whereas on Apache it's the other way round.

Comment: there are .htaccess files at every level to allow custom access to each directory to a range of IP Addresses. For example I may want only the accounts office to be able to access /organisation/accounts/ whilst them and head office could access /organisation/

Comment: would Satisfy any and Satisfy all be the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> require valid-user
> <RequireAny>
>     Require ip x.x.x.x
> </RequireAny>
> ```

This would seem to be overkill for Apache 2.4. `<RequireAny>` is the default container. The above 4 lines is the same as the one-line `Require ip x.x.x.x`.

However, my experience with LiteSpeed is that it behaves more like an Apache 2.2 server and (annoyingly) *silently* fails on directives it does not understand (although there might be something logged in the server's error log).

Try the following (Apache 2.2 style) directives instead:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from x.x.x.x
```

Comment: I've added some more code above explaining why I used <RequireAny> because I actually had multiple IPs listed there.

The <RequireAll> and <RequireAny> functions allows me to do a combination of password and/or IP address restrictions however Order Allow,Deny
Allow from x.x.x.x wouldn't give me this functionality would it ?